# finding delimeters, removing them, and returning an array without them

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that will count the amount of delimiters in an array which my delimiters is the comma. So it will find where the delimiters are and then remove them and then return an array without the delimiters. Here is what I have so far.

```
function getDelimiterLocations(line, delimiter) {
    var i;
    var result;
    for(i=0; i<line.length; i++);
    {
        if(i<line.length)
        {
            result= line.indexOf(delimiter);
        }
        else
        {
            result= "";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What exception are you getting? Also, you have a semicolon right after the parentheses on your for loop, which is probably going to mess up everything

Comment: Also, you're just erasing the previous value in the result variable each time. What's the point of this function?

Comment: Maybe you looking for this `line.split(delimeter)`

Comment: or if your looking to just strip out the delimiter, ```line.replace(","," ");```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `line` is a string(as earlier it was tagged as JAVA) then you can do it using `split()` like shown below. Pass the delimiter to the split() function based on which you want to split your input into Array.

> In Java

```
public static String[] func(){
    String str = "b,d,d,b";
    return str.split(",");
}
```

> In Javascript

```
function func(){
 var str = "a,b,c,d";
 console.log(str.split(","));
}
```